# I am running a BFGS optimization with certain bounds. What could be the reason for my optimization to always go toward the bound before converging?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I am running a geometry optimization of a molecule and minimizing with respect to extracted DFT energies of the molecule. Following is my BFGS command:

```
res = minimize(fun,x0, method='L-BFGS-B',bounds=([3.0,5.0]),options={'ftol': 1e-08,'gtol':1e-4,'eps':1e-04})
```

where `fun` extracts the energy of the energy of the molecule as the guessed distance and `x0` is the initial guess.

Comment: Please provide `fun` and all your imports so that we have a minimal reproducible example we can run.